# Invisible(not gone) back button in the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, invisible

Question is very simple but solution I have tried so many things. I want to **Invisible** the back button on the Action bar Not gone.

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_white);
```

I have tried this so far. But It actually remove the back-button from the Action bar. I want it to be just **Invisible**.

Comment: That is unusual approach, but I suppose you have reasons. First thing drops on my mind is instead of hiding it, maybe you can replace it with transparent button?

Comment: The ripple effect will remain even if I make back button transparent

Answer (score 1):

*Hey android_griezmann*

There is one very simple solution for it to use appBar layout and add it in yor layout and you can manage it as you want.

app_bar_layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/appTurquoiseColor">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                   <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/service_info"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Toolbar Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:customTypeFace="dosis_book" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/service_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/info"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </merge>
```

Comment: is it working perfectly, if yes then accept the ans otherwise we find the another way.

Comment: See it will definitely work but it's like i am searching for the Android SDK solution if there any..